# More taxonomy filter: how to show results?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two custom taxonomies.

I wanna filter my product,obtaining the same result of this wp_query.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'auto',
            'field' => 'ID',
            'terms' => $auto_id
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ricambio',
            'field' => 'ID',
            'terms' => $ricambi_id
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'title',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How i show this filtering result ?
I have to create a template like taxonomy-auto-ricambio.php ? archive-auto-ricambio ?

If i in my url address write like this:

```
http://www.myshop.com/?auto=my_auto&ricambio=my_ricambio
```

it works.

How can i show it in a template with a pretty url ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much pulling this directly from this excellent article on [advanced taxonomies with pretty urls](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/).

First create some new re-write rules. This should probably be in a site-specific snippets plugin and NOT in your theme. Then go to permalinks and re-save your permalinks.

```
function so_25722819_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'event/(industry|location)/(.+?)/(industry|location)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=eg_event&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),
        'event/(industry|location)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=eg_event&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'so_25722819_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Now if you visit your site with the url:

> www.example.com/auto/my_auto/ricambio/my_ricambio

You should go to a taxonomy archive page that shows the same result as:

> www.example.com/?auto=my_auto&ricambio=my_ricambio

To echo out these pretty permalinks you can use the plugin the article author provided, with just a tiny adjustment to switch from his `eg_events` post type to your `product` post type.

```
function eg_get_filter_permalink( $taxonomy_slug, $term ) {
    global $wp_query;

    // If there is already a filter running for this taxonomy
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy_slug] ) ){
        // And the term for this URL is not already being used to filter the taxonomy
        if( strpos( $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy_slug], $term ) === false ) {
            // Append the term
            $filter_query = $taxonomy_slug . '/' . $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy_slug] . '+' . $term;
        } else {
            // Otherwise, remove the term
            if( $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy_slug] == $term ) {
                $filter_query = '';
            } else {
                $filter = str_replace( $term, '', $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy_slug] );
                // Remove any residual + symbols left behind
                $filter = str_replace( '++', '+', $filter );
                $filter = preg_replace( '/(^\+|\+$)/', '', $filter );
                $filter_query = $taxonomy_slug . '/' . $filter;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $filter_query = $taxonomy_slug . '/' . $term;
    }

    // Maintain the filters for other taxonomies
    if( isset( $wp_query->tax_query ) ) {

        foreach( $wp_query->tax_query->queries as $query ) {

            $tax = get_taxonomy( $query['taxonomy'] );

            // Have we already handled this taxonomy?
            if( $tax->query_var == $taxonomy_slug )
                continue;

            // Make sure taxonomy hasn't already been added to query string
            if( strpos( $existing_query, $tax->query_var ) === false )
                $existing_query .= $tax->query_var . '/' . $wp_query->query_vars[$tax->query_var] . '/';
        }

    }

    if( isset( $existing_query ) )
        $filter_query = $existing_query . $filter_query;

    return trailingslashit( get_post_type_archive_link( 'product' ) . $filter_query );
}
```

Then in any template you can use the above function to generate a pretty permalink to your multiple taxonomy archive:

```
// Link to page with only my_ricambio in my_auto 
echo eg_get_filter_permalink( 'my_auto', 'my_ricambio' );
```